# Emulating Logic-AND gate

Tags: transistors, schematics, logic-gates

The following is an image of the AND logic gate from [electronics-tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_2.html) and my representation of that in EveryCircuit, where I've used the "Logic input" as the A/B inputs on the left (equivalent to a 5V battery).

[image]

Is this the correct representation of the AND circuit? Additionally, what is the usual voltage or current requirement for an A/B input to be considered in the 'on' position?

Comment: See also similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/508854/3288) and its answers

Answer (score 3):

That circuit isn't very good.

> ... what is the usual voltage or current requirement for an A/B input to be considered in the 'on' position?

It's whatever you define it to be based on what you consider acceptable as high and low on the output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMF7Jx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The problem.*

The problem is that the Q1 and Q2 will behave differently. If input B is pulled high then current will flow through R2, Q2's base-emitter junction (which is a diode, remember) and to your output.

On the other hand, if B is off and A is on you won't get the same diode behavior.

The circuit might perform adequately for some application but it's not true logic. 
Have a look at how AND gates are done in TTL logic to get a better idea of how it's done.

Comment: `Have a look at how AND gates are done in TTL logic to get a better idea of how it's done.` would this be solved by adding a diode before R1 and R2?

Comment: Is that what you found? How do you think it would help?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of R2 is to absorb the bias current that comes though the base of the lower transistor.

if you want to drive a LED from this gate connect it  and its resistor  to the output, instead of inserting it into the circuit.