# Using two NPN transistors to form an AND gate

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

I'm a little puzzled by this schematic and am wondering if this is correct?
[image]

When I wire this up with 2N222 transistors and supply 5V at VCC with all 10K ohm resistors, and A and B are GND, the meter measurement at OUT is 0. If A and B are VCC, then OUT is close to VCC.  All good. Now if B is GND, while A is VCC, OUT is GND, also good. However, when A is GND and B is VCC, I see approx 2V at OUT. I was expecting GND. Is this because the collector on the bottom transistor does not have any voltage and current is flowing from the base to the emitter?  If so, is this schematic incorrect for an AND gate?

Comment: can you, in the future, please not remove the designators on the components (Q in case of your transistors), and use your schematic tool's (kicad) "annotate" functionality to number them (R1, R2, R3), so that discussing the effects of components becomes possible without always having to write something like "the middle resistor".

Comment: No, it's not an AND gate - who says it is?

Comment: When I google implementing an AND gate using transistors I seem to always find this layout. Note sparkfun, for example, has it at this link. https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/1/9/3/logic-and-circuit.png

Comment: And here is another link showing the same thing.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/trangate.html

Answer (score 3):

OK, definitely seems like they're a lot of schematics on the net that shows an AND gate as I posted originally that are wrong. The following schematic appears to work perfectly for me which I found on a youtube video on constructing an AND gate using transistors.

[image]

Comment: Yes, have a look at my answer too, which explains why/when the AND BJT does/does not work.  This is indeed how to make it work: a NAND BJT plus an inverter.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not correct. Current flows from base to emitter, even if collector is at 0V, so this circuit will not function as an AND gate when it is made from bipolar junction transistors.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it works or not depends on the circumstances.

With B high and A low there is still a current flowing from B through R_B and R_out (Rs are not labeled in diagram, but I think it's clear which ones I mean).

That current has a voltage across R_out. Whether the voltage is deemed high (close to 5V) or low (close to 0V) depends on the choice of R values as well as the R of the load attached at OUT.

For instance, for R_B = 1K and R_load = 100 you get a 10:1 voltage divider (for R_out much larger than R_load, the divider is dominated by the small R_load and the R_B), which means that the output voltage over R_out is just under 0.5V, accounting for the V_BE drop. You might consider this a good "low" for keeping an LED off.

However, the larger your R_load, the higher the output voltage becomes, in the case of "B high and A low", which is why this is not a good circuit if this output is connected to the input of another similar BJT logic circuit that has a high input of 1K. That input becomes the load for this circuit.

The NAND BJT, in contrast to a AND BJT, has the load on the collector side of the transistor pair, and works better for connecting its output to a high-R input of a subsequent logic circuit.

To create a AND from a NAND you'd have to connect an additional inverter.

Here is a NAND BJT:

[image]

From http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/trangate.html